# Vega PPT/Bios reset before moving to a rig?

Tags: gpu-mining, mining-hardware

I have an MSI Vega 56 I flashed to 64 bios and applied a soft power play table.  This was in my everyday rig and I want to move it to an open air setup in the basement. I’ve removed the card from my everyday rig and set it up on a gifted setup. The motherboard is an old GA-MA770T-UD3P with Phenom II x2 550 (I think). I installed Win 10, updated, tried to install drivers, and BSOD during install. Looks to be a common issue on older boards with PCIE2 slots and nonUEFI bios.  Some noted it would work on Win 7 so I’m trying that now but I’m wondering if I need to restore the 56 bios + remove the SPPT while it’s connected to my every day rig. Anyone have thoughts?